# Using SQL JOIN and COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Let there be two tables, one holding user information and one holding user records of some sort, say receipts. There is a one-to-many relationship between the users and receipts.

What would be the best SQL method of retrieving users, sorted by the greatest number of receipts?

The best way I can think of is using a join and count(?) to return an array of users and their number of associated receipts.

Is there a way to make use of the count function in this instance?

```
select * from `users` inner join `receipts` on `users`.`id` = `receipts`.`uId`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two answers provided by Dave and meewoK will accomplish what you need. I'm providing an alternative, which *should* provide better performance and allow you to show more user information because in the case with Dave's answer you can only SELECT columns that are used by an aggregate function or in the group clause.

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, r.numReceipts  
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT uId, count(receipts) as numReceipts
   FROM receipts
   GROUP BY receipts.id
) as r ON r.uId = u.id
ORDER BY r.numReceipts DESC
```

This creates an inline view. Only return the count of receipts of each user and then join this inline view on the user's ID.

Some one correct me if I'm wrong, but I've been told that the planner isn't as efficient when you do a scalar subquery in the SELECT clause. It's better to join on a temporary table this way. There are multiple ways to write this query and it all depends on how you want to use the information!!! Cheers!

Comment: tbh I have no idea which is faster I suspect my way of doing it was considerably slower (certainly on larger tables) as your doing a full table b scan and count for each uid from table a.  My answer also depends on him not wanting any data from the receipts table where as yours gives him that :) though tbh a sub select in a join probably isn't the best way of doing it either.  I'd be tempted to do an outer left join if I wanted a counter and retrieve the details of both tables.  Or perhaps a union and just select the whole lot :)

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree a left join is the most efficient way of handling this task.

Answer (score 6):

If OP wishes to include additional information (additional aggregations, etc...) utilizing data from `users` table:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,
       count(`receipts`.`uId`)
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `receipts` ON `users`.`id` = `receipts`.`uId`
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
ORDER BY count(`receipts`.`uId`) DESC
```

Otherwise, only the `receipts` table is required...

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,
       count(`receipts`.`uId`)
FROM `receipts`
GROUP BY `receipts`.`uId`
ORDER BY count(`receipts`.`uId`) DESC
```

Comment: . . If you are going to limit the return to only the id, the join is not necessary.

Comment: . . This query is still wrong, unless their happens to be a column called `receipts` in the `receipts` table.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SELECT a.`id`, count(b.`recipts`) as total_receipts
FROM `users` a
INNER JOIN `receipts` b
ON a.`id` = b.`uId`
GROUP BY a.`id` 
ORDER BY count(b.`receipts`) desc
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT users.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblreceipts WHERE tblreciepts.uId=users.id) as counter FROM`users`ORDER BY counter DESC`

Something like this may work (not sure on the speed though if its big tables)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include all users, even those with no receipts, then a good way is a `left outer join`:

```
SELECT u.*, count(r.uid) as NumReceipts
FROM `users` u left outer join
     `receipts` r
    ON u.id = r.`uId
GROUP BY `u.id
ORDER BY NumReceipts DESC;
```

If you only want the id for users that have receipts, then the join is not even necessary:

```
SELECT r.uid, count(*) as NumReceipts
FROM receipts r
GROUP BY r.uid
ORDER BY NumReceipts
```